# Problem with Connecting to Unknown Private Network on Metamask

Tags: metamask

When I try to create a custom RPC on http://localhost:3000/ on Metamask, it keeps on trying to connect to it. It has not moved past "Connecting to Unknown Private Network" on the Metamask extension. What am I doing wrong and how to solve this issue?

Comment: With me this happens sometimes but when I close the metamask tab and open it again it usually fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you did start the RPC server on port 3000? If you use Truffle or Ganache, your (with `npm run start`) web application runs on port 3000, but the RPC from Ganache usually runs on http://127.0.0.1:7545 or http://127.0.0.1:8545 .

Comment: How do I know which server RPC is running on? How do I specify the server?

Answer (score 0):

As TheCooocy highlighted in his answer, this happens when the RPC port is run on a different port than the web application port.

```
 geth --identity “LocalTestNode” --rpc --rpcport 8080 --rpccorsdomain “*” --datadir ~/mychain/data/ --port 0 --nodiscover --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --networkid 1999 --maxpeers 0 console
```

My RPC port here was 8080 and when I did that it worked.